# WCF Service class static constructor called in every call

Tags: wcf, static-constructor

I have a Service class implementing a contract as follows:

```
interface IContractFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

Class ServiceFoo() : IContractFoo
{
    public static ServiceFoo()
    {
        Log("Static constructor called");
    }

    void Foo()
    {
        Log("Foo called");
    } 
}
```

What i am finiding is that each time the Foo API is called, the static constructor gets called. So, the log looks like this -

> Static constructor called
>   Foo called
>   Static constructor called
>   Foo called

This should not be happening since this is a static constructor. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I found out that this is happening because WCF/ASP.NET is creating a new appdomain per request. Have to figure out how to stop this from happening. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 2):

By default, WCF services use a "per-call" model. I don't think that marking the constructor with `static` will change that behavior. You can change this using the `ServiceBehavior` attribute or by changing the ServiceBehavior settings in the web.config file associated with this service.

Here are a couple articles that might help you decide which model is appropriate for your services:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: I found out that this is happening because WCF/ASP.NET is creating a new appdomain per request. Have to figure out how to stop this from happening. Comments welcome.

Comment: Prapti, where do you found it?